# AS3 URLLoader + ByteArray vs Loader class for loading images

Tags: actionscript-3, air, arrays

Can anyone tell me why using the URLLoaderclass, then converting loaded data to a Byte array, is (apparently)a lot quicker then simply using the Loader Class?

http://blog.aspectvision.com/2008/11/as3-careful-with-loaderload/

The Loader class is supposed to be what is used for simply loading image data, so what gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is expected to be like that.
Loader class is a display class (extends DisplayObjectContainer) and also does quite a few checks internally opposed to URLLoader class which only extends EventDispatcher and loads raw bytes => BINARY and is not expecting the data to have any format or type.

Even so used like in the example (i don't know the whole context so i might be wrong) doesn't make to much sense. Using loadBytes function from a loader is fast indeed but keeping it inside a Loader class it is an unnecessary overhead. When used loadBytes like that it makes more sense to use a single Loader object as a tool and not as an object in the display list.